# Python read data from file and convert to double precision

Tags: python, numpy

I've been reading an ASCII data file using python. Then I covert the data into a numpy array.
However, I've noticed that the numbers are being rounded.

E.g. My original value from the file is:  2368999.932089

which python has rounded to: 2368999.93209

here is an example of my code:

```
import numpy as np
datafil = open("test.txt",'r')

tempvar = []
header = datafil.readline()
for line in datafil:
    word = line.split()
    char = word[0]      # take the first element word[0] of the list
    word.pop()          # remove the last element from the list "word"
    if char[0:3] >= '224' and char[0:3] < '225':
        tempvar.append(word)

strvar = np.array(tempvar,dtype = np.longdouble)  # Here I want to read all data as double
print(strvar.shape)

var = strvar[:,0:23]
print(var[0,22])      # here it prints 2368999.93209 but the actual value is  2368999.932089
```

Any ideas guys?

Abedin

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Please provide the correct code: your comments are not python comments.

Comment: I am sorry @Daniel. I've just corrected the comments in my code!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a problem of your code. It's the usual floating point representation in Python. See
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

I think when you print it, `print` already formatted your number to str

```
In [1]: a=2368999.932089

In [2]: print a
2368999.93209

In [3]: str(a)
Out[3]: '2368999.93209'

In [4]: repr(a)
Out[4]: '2368999.932089'

In [5]: a-2368999.93209
Out[5]: -9.997747838497162e-07
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do, but simplified with test.txt containing only

```
asdf
2368999.932089
```

and then the code:

```
import numpy as np
datafil = open("test.txt",'r')

tempvar = []
header = datafil.readline()
for line in datafil:
    tempvar.append(line)
print(tempvar)
strvar = np.array(tempvar, dtype=np.float)
print(strvar.shape)
print(strvar)
```

I get the following output:

```
$ python3 so.py 
['2368999.932089']
(1,)
[ 2368999.932089]
```

which seems to be working fine.

**Edit**: Updated with your provided line, so test.txt is

```
asdf
t JD a e incl lasc aper truean rdnnode RA Dec RArate Decrate metdr1 metddr1 metra1 metdec1 metbeta1 metdv1 metsl1 metarrJD1 beta JDej name 223.187263 2450520.619348 3.12966 0.61835 70.7196 282.97 171.324 -96.2738 1.19968 325.317 35.8075 0.662368 0.364967 0.215336 3.21729 -133.586 46.4884 59.7421 37.7195 282.821 2450681.900221 0 2368999.932089 EH2003
```

and the code

```
import numpy as np
datafil = open("test.txt",'r')

tempvar = []
header = datafil.readline()
for line in datafil:
    tempvar.append(line.split(' '))
print(tempvar)
strvar = np.array(tempvar[0][-2], dtype=np.float)
print(strvar)
```

the last `print` still outputs `2368999.932089` for me. So I'm guessing this is a platform issue? What happens if you force `dtype=np.float64` or `dtype=np.float128`? Some other sanity checks: have you tried spitting out the text before it is converted to a float? And what do you get from doing something like:

```
>>> np.array('2368999.932089')
array('2368999.932089', 
  dtype='<U14')
>>> float('2368999.932089')
2368999.932089
```

Comment: Hi @Alex Z! Strangely, I did exactly as in your example but it still produces 236899.93209. Unfortunately, I can't copy and paste my data file as it contains 70 million lines and 24 columns.

Comment: Is there still an issue with a simple one line test file?

Comment: hi again! There is no problem when I use the sample data and code you have provided. It prints the number as it is supposed to.
I don't really understand why it rounds it in my original code???

Comment: can you post one or two rows of the original file? Is there anything strange/unusual about the file encoding, or is it just plain text?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem: `In [9]: strvar= np.array([2368999.932089],dtype = np.longdouble)

In [10]: print strvar[0]
2368999.93209
`

Comment: Or even simpler: `In [12]: print 2368999.932089
2368999.93209
`

Comment: @AlexZ and @Happy001, here is the first line of the original file:

` t JD a e incl lasc aper truean rdnnode RA Dec RArate Decrate metdr1 metddr1 metra1 metdec1 metbeta1 metdv1 metsl1 metarrJD1 beta JDej name 
 223.187263   2450520.619348 3.12966 0.61835 70.7196 282.97 171.324 -96.2738 1.19968 325.317 35.8075 0.662368 0.364967 0.215336 3.21729 -133.586 46.4884 59.7421 37.7195 282.821 2450681.900221 0 2368999.932089 EH2003`

Comment: I am sorry guys, I don't know how to post it in more readable format!

Comment: @Happy001 and Alex Z, thank you so much for your help. But I also think that maybe Python rounds the number as it prints on the screen but actually keeps the number of decimal places. I added 0.000001 to strvar[0] and it printed 2368999.93209 which should be the correct values since strvar[0] is supposed to have the value 2368999.932089. Anyways, it is kind of odd that Python does that as it prevents one from keeping a track of the precision.